# Is that possible to keep one network running two versions of corda app

Tags: corda

we raise this question due to each time when we deploy a new version of Corda application, previous created data could not be proceed due to we updated some structure of the objects in the system. And we only can clean previous data. But we would like to check one question, whether we can keep two versions in one application, to make previous data and new data can work together properly. Not sure whether this is possible but would like to ask here. Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, provided you are sensible about the way you upgrade the CorDap's states, contracts and flows.

See the full upgrade guide here: https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html, and the section on type evolution here: https://docs.corda.net/serialization.html#type-evolution.